# Can PHP 7.3.3 Support PostgreSQL 13?

Tags: php, postgresql

So far I've been using my application with PHP 7.3.3 and PostgreSQL 11. Today I upgraded the version of PostgreSQL to 13, and now I'm seeing the error "CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection". Do I need to make any configuration changes from my previous settings in `application/config/config.php`, or is it just that PostgreSQL 13 is not at all supported by PHP 7.3.3?
P.S. the database name and the password are the same, and I've checked on this several times.

Comment: Are you on `7.3.3` or `7.3.33`? If you are on `7.3.3`, my first reaction would be to upgrade your PHP version, too.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I'm at 7.3.3 only. And yes I'm thinking of upgrading the php version as well, but I just want to know why am I getting the failed connection error with 7.3.3. Is it because of incompatibility?

Comment: I unfortunately don't know, but I think it would be a pretty safe upgrade to perform, and if you were locked at `7.3.3` for any other reason, I think that would be a bigger blocker security-wise

Comment: Keep in mind that PHP 7.3 is horribly outdated, it was first released in Dec 2018, while PostgreSQL 13 was released in 2020. If you need help with that, please share the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: More information needed 1) OS and version? 2) How did you upgrade to Postgres 13? 3) Is the server running? 4) Can you connect using [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)? **Add answers as update to question**.